# Scala regex splitting on InputStream

Tags: performance, scala, functional-programming, inputstream

I'm parsing a resource file and splitting on empty lines, using the following code:

```
val inputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("foo.txt")
val source = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)
val fooString = source.mkString
val fooParsedSections = fooString.split("\\r\\n[\\f\\t ]*\\r\\n")
```

I believe this is pulling the input stream into memory as a full string, and then splitting on the regex. This works fine for the relatively small file I'm parsing, but it's not ideal and I'm curious how I could improve it--

Two ideas are:

1. read the input stream line-by-line and have a buffer of segments that I build up, splitting on empty lines
2. read the stream character-by-character and parse segments based off of a small finite state machine

However, I'd love to not maintain a mutable buffer if possible.

Any suggestions? This is just for a personal fun project, and I want to learn how to do this in an efficent and functional manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream.span`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream@span(p:A=>Boolean):(Repr,Repr)) method to get the prefix before the empty line, then repeat. Here's a helper function for that:

```
def sections(lines: Stream[String]): Stream[String] = {
  if (lines.isEmpty) Stream.empty
  else {
    // cutting off the longest `prefix` before an empty line
    val (prefix, suffix) = lines.span { _.trim.nonEmpty }
    // dropping any empty lines (there may be several)
    val rest = suffix.dropWhile{ _.trim.isEmpty }

    // grouping back the prefix lines and calling recursion
    prefix.mkString("\n") #:: sections(rest)
  }
}
```

Note, that `Stream`'s method `#::` is lazy and doesn't evaluate the right operand until it's needed. Here is how you can apply it to your use case:

```
val inputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("foo.txt")
val source = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)
val parsedSections = sections(source.getLines.toStream)
```

[Source.getLines](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.io.Source@getLines():Iterator[String])
 method returns `Iterator[String]` which we convert to `Stream` and apply the helper function. You can also call `.toIterator` in the end if you process the groups of lines on the way and don't need to store them. See the [`Stream`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) docs for details.

**EDIT**

If you still want to use regex, you can change `.trim.nonEmpty` in the function above to the use of the `String` [`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) method.